# 1200% CPU usage by postgres user

Tags: postgresql

I've just recently installed PostgreSQL on an Ubuntu Server machine and there are currently no queries or clients connected to the databases, it's just sitting there idle. Out of curiosity I installed glances and this is what I saw:

[image: 1]

With Postgres just sitting there and idling, it's says it's using 1200% of the CPU which if you ask me is quite high. But the overall CPU usage is around 75% with NOTHING running, just Postgres (no clients connected, no queries...)

Any idea what's causing it?

EDIT: I think the pros in the comments were right. I ran `last` and saw a postgres user log on from an IP in Germany, probably through an open SSH or PostgreSQL port that I forgot to close. I'm still learning the usage of Ubuntu so I'm not surprised that happened.
I just reinstalled the Ubuntu-Server OS on the server and I hope that got rid od the malware.
Now I know not to leave open ports over the weekends when testing stuff!

Comment: As the command is `bash` it's unlikely the Postgres service, but rather something that is executed under the `postgres` user account. Maybe you have been hacked

Comment: That doesn't soud too good. By killing the `postgres` user the usage dropped back down. Is it possible that I made a mistake by opening port 5432 with `ufw`

Comment: I deleted the `postgres` user and reinstalled PostgreSQL, and as soon as I start the main cluster the usage jumps up to 1200%. I didn't configure anything for remote access, just started the cluster with `sudo pg_ctlcluster 12 main start`.

Comment: You should investigate what exactly that `bash` command is doing that is using so much CPU. But [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) is a better place to ask that I think

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help! I'll see what I can do and should I report it back here?

Comment: As mentioned, you may have been hacked and have a coin miner or something running as the postgres user. Just reinstalling that service & user will likely not be enough to eradicate the problem as it cuold have infected other parts of the system too. Small note in case you are unaware: 1200% isn't as odd a number from `top` as it may seem, it suggests that the process is using 12 cores worth of CPU time (12*100%).

Comment: So I guess reinstalling the OS would fix that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with glances.  What does a  more traditional tool like `top` show?